# Search packages for foreign architecture

Tags: command-line, apt

How can we search for packages, like `apt-cache search` but for foreign architectures?

E.g. My system is `amd64` but I have also `arm64` as foreign architecture in `dpkg` and I want to search for `arm64`.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I am looking for a command line solution

Answer (score 1):

Use [the Package Index](https://packages.ubuntu.com). After searching for a package name, you can select a specific architecture. For example, searching for `gcc`, in `arm64`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=arm64&searchon=names&keywords=gcc

> [image]

If you have arm64 sources added to apt, You can use `aptitude`:

```
$ aptitude search '~n apache2-dev'
p   apache2-dev                                - Apache HTTP Server (development headers)
p   apache2-dev:arm64                          - Apache HTTP Server (development headers)
$ aptitude search '~n apache2-dev ~r arm64'
p   apache2-dev:arm64                          - Apache HTTP Server (development headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am looking for a command line solution :)

Comment: @Tanasis use a command line web browser. `lynx` or the like.

Comment: True, but unfortunately It's an embedded board and I don't want to install unnecessary stuff :( I was wondering if there is something wrt `dpkg` or `apt`. Towards those lines...